# Angular2 pb with observable in guard when refresh in the guarded route

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, guard

I have a problem with guard and observable :( 
The pb is that I don't want to be redirected when i refresh my page on a guarded route when the user's roles are good. Is anyone could help me please :)

Here is the method in my service :

```
isAllowedToBeThere(allowedRoles: string[]) {
    if (this.authService.isLogged()) {
        return this.roles$.map( (roles) => {
            if (_.difference(allowedRoles, roles).length < allowedRoles.length) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Here my guard :

```
if (route.data['roles'].length > 0) {
  let allowedRoles: string[] = route.data['roles'];
        this.userService.isAllowedToBeThere(allowedRoles)
            .do( isAllowed => {
                if (!isAllowed) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/foo']);
                }
            });

    }
```

Some explanation: 
When I refresh my page, my userservice just reload the current user in a subscription, so i get back the roles and "next" them into the roles$ observable prop. It appears that the CanActivate method is processed too soon so it always false. The roles$ observable is set in an other method which is called in my constructor userservice.

I know that the observable should be completed in order to be getted by the guard but i tried some codes and that didn't work either. So if anyone knows how to achieve this ? :)

Thank you very much for your help !! :)